# Flash button only working in certain area?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I am completely new to flash cs6. I just want to ask that why buttons are only working in certain areas? Is that true? Or is it dealing with the centre points? Qustions described in pictures. Thank you in advance

[image: question description]

[image: center points]

Comment: Check if there are mouse-enabled objects that are invisible and overlap your button if you place it there.

Comment: oh that's true I have a movie clip with its alpha set to 0%.

Comment: but i need it to show when i click the button, what should i do with it?

Comment: You can, for example, `addChild()` it with 100% alpha once the button is clicked, and not keep it there while you don't want to. Of course you will need to alter its x&y coordinates for proper placement.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution here will be to add below line of code,

```
youralphamovieclip.mouseEnabled = false;
```